# Rust complains about generic argument not satisfying trait bound even though it is not required

Tags: rust, traits

I'm trying to compile following rust code:

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Foo<Data> {
    f: fn(&Data),
}

trait Trait : Clone {
    type DataType;
}

// throws:
// error[E0277]: the trait bound `Data: std::clone::Clone` is not satisfied
impl<Data> Trait for Foo<Data> {
    type DataType = Data;
}
```

It complains about `Data` generic argument not satisfying `Clone` constraint, even though it is not supposed to.

From my understanding `Foo<Data>` should support `Clone` without need for `Data` to support it.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `derive` for `Clone` sometimes adds `where` constraints that are restrictive. As of May 2020, it is still an open bug. See: [#[derive] sometimes uses incorrect bounds · Issue #26925 · rust-lang/rust](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/26925).

A workaround is to implement `Clone` manually for this struct. For example:

```rust
impl<Data> Clone for Foo<Data> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        Self { f: self.f }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.

It is a bit weird, though. Problem only arises when I add `impl Trait`. Without it derive succeeds just fine.

Do you by any chance know of any workarounds that don't require manual clone?

Comment: The derive's impl has `where Data: Clone`, and that on its own is okay (despite it being a `derive` issue in this specific case). Now it is important to understand because of this, `Foo<Data>: Clone` does not hold unless `Data : Clone` as well. So far so good.

Now for the trait and the `impl`. Because we have `Trait : Clone`, then the `impl` demands `Foo<Data>: Clone`, and therefore `Data: Clone`. However, the `impl` does not restrict for `Data: Clone`, and therefore the failure.

Comment: Why didn't it fail right away on struct definition?
Because Data is not constrained there either.

Comment: There's nothing in the struct definition itself that requires `Clone` from `Data`, therefore it is remains valid. Say, if you have a `struct Bar {}` that is does not implement `Clone`, you can declare `let x : Foo<Bar> = Foo { f: |_| {} };` and it will compile. However if you try to add `let y = x.clone();` it will not build because `Foo<Bar>: Clone` does not hold.

Comment: Ah, I see. I think I understand. Derive only adds implementation if all the members support Clone. I was under the impression that it's unconditional. Thanks.

Comment: It's unconditional, but the type logic in the compiler only considers the implementation for types for which the implementation is relevant, based on `where`.